# Why can't I type with some keys on my laptop?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, laptop

After I installed Ubuntu 12.10, I noticed that some keys on my Asus A53U laptop have stopped working correctly, and others work for the wrong keys, i.e. I press the key below backspace (can't remember what it's called) and it prints a tilde, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> prints **"** and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> prints **@**.

It shouldn't be a hardware issue, as it worked with Windows 7 a few days prior. the keys that don't work are: <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, and <kbd>7</kbd>. I've been researching, and it seemed like it was a driver issue, as I have no drivers installed, because I had to do a factory reset because my laptop crashed a while ago.

Also, the entire mouse touch pad and keys don't work after I log into my user. If I sign in as a guest, however, the touch pad works. The keyboard still has the same problems though.

If anyone has any clue or a solution, help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You most likely have the wrong keyboard layout selected in Settings. However, 12.10 has been EOL (i.e. not supported) since 2013. You may want to install 14.04, 15.10 or even 12.04 if you like 12.

Comment: Set my keyboard to the correct layout, yet the same keys still don't work..
any other tips? And anything on the mouse touch pad

Comment: You may have a defective keyboard.

Comment: But you should really upgrade to 14.04 or 15.10

Answer (score 0):

Numlock may be on. And the layout is set to GB
**sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup** Might help to set it to the correct layout again.

Comment: what else would I do to configure that properly? I haven't a clue what I'm doing with Ubuntu.. never used it before

Comment: In that case I would suggest either reinstalling it or getting the latest version from Ubuntu.com, as it will have better support and you can configure the keyboard layout during install. [Although this youtube video might help](https://youtu.be/ByR3uTWe1yl)